# How to handle nested reactive properties in reactive programming?

Tags: reactive

When building an application or program using the concepts of reactive programming, how does this work for nested reactive properties?

I have an example using Swift, [ReactiveKit](https://github.com/DeclarativeHub/ReactiveKit), and [Bond](https://github.com/DeclarativeHub/Bond), however the concepts apply to any reactive programming setup.

```
class User {
    var firstName: Observable<String>

    init(firstName: String) {
        self.firstName = Observable<String>(firstName)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var user: Observable<User> = Observable<User>(User.init(firstName: "Bob"))
    @IBOutlet let label: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        user.firstName.bind(to: label)
    }

    @IBAction func updateUser() {
        WebService.retrieveUserFromServer { [weak self] user in
            self?.user.value = user
        }
    }
}
```

So in the example above, I want the label to be updated whenever the `user` or `user.firstName` is updated. But currently, if `updateUser` gets called, and a new `user` instance is passed in, the `bind` to the label doesn't work anymore.

So in this example, the `firstName` can be updated directly, or the entire `user` instance can be updated. Of course there is a way to maybe use some combine functions to add a listener for when `user` gets updated or `user.firstName` gets updated and handle it then. But that gets extremely messy very quickly, especially as you add more properties to `User`.

How are you supposed to handle these types of cases in reactive programming? Where you have a parent property that is reactive, and properties that are reactive within that class, and you want to react based on either the parent being updated, or any of the children properties being updated.

Answer (score 0):

First, Observables should never be `var`s, they should only ever be `let`s. You don't want to reseat an Observable because that will break all the bindings.

Second, your code uses passive (rather than reactive) programming in the @IBAction. I use RxSwift/RxCocoa but I expect that Bond has a reactive wrapper around IBActions that you can use.

Third, `retrieveUserFromServer` should return an Observable rather than use a callback closure.

But none of the above addresses your fundamental question. How should one deal with nested Observables? In RxSwift, we use `flatMap` for this purpose. In Combine, the same behavior can be achieved with `map/switchToLatest`.

In RxSwift:

```
user
    .flatMapLatest { $0.firstName }
    .bind(to: label.rx.text)
```

In Combine:

```
user
    .map { $0.firstName }
    .switchToLatest()
    .sink { [label] value in
        label?.text = value
    }
```

I expect that ReactiveKit with Bond would look similar to one or both of the above.